# In a union-subclass mapping, how can the subclass declare required dependencies?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm puzzling over adding a `@ManyToOne(optional=false)` entity mapping to a class that is a subclass participating in a union-subclass mapping. The setup looks something like that:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen", sequenceName = "id_seq", 
            initialValue =  1, allocationSize = 1)
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, 
         CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
    protected Person person;
}

@Entity
public class A extends Role {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Status status = Status.INIT;
}

@Entity
public class B extends Role {
    String login;
}
```

This works fine for all purposes I've used it so far. Now, I was modifying a detached `Person` that also had `B` role (previously fetched together) and tried to persist the changes via:

```
entityManager.merge(person);
```

The line executed a series of select statements to reload the entity graph, including one that looked like this:

```
select role0_.id, role0_.person_id, role0_.login, role0_.status_id,
    person1_.id,
    status2_.id, status2_.code, status2_.visible
from
    (select id, person_id, login, null::int8 as status_id, 1 as clazz_
        from public.A
    union all select id, person_id, null::varchar as login, status_id, 2 as clazz_
        from public.B) role0_
inner join public.Person person1_ on role0_.person_id = person1_.id
inner join public.Status status2_ on role0_.status_id = status2_.id
where role0_.id=?
```

After this statement I got an exception:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find my.company.Role with id 2

Part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find my.company.Role with id 2
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:181) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:263) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:952) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:681) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:499) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:518) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:661) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:177) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:374) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:311) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:153) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.CR1.jar:4.3.0.CR1]
```

Problem was that entity with `Role.id = 2` was of class `B`, so had no `status_id` and was thus not present in the select resultset.

My question is rather simple: are required attributes as described above not supported by Hibernate/JPA and if yes, what can I do to document and enforce "non-nullness" of this dependency?